# Same-Origin Policy and serving JS from a CDN

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I want to serve my JavaScript scripts from a CDN like cloudflare.

Now my scripts communicate with my app server via ajax. Wouldn't the same-origin policy restrictions come into play when I load these scripts from a CDN?

Let's say my app is on the domain:

```
http://app.com
```

And I load my scripts from

```
http://cdn.com/xyz/all.js
```

Now, since my scripts are loaded from a different domain than the domain my app is running from, I guess the same origin policy would prevent me from doing ajax communication with my app.

Am I getting something wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, it will work. That's why JSONP works. **The "origin" of the script is the page it is executed in, not where it comes from.**

As you asked for it, here's a reference (I couldn't find any better, but Crockford is well known)

> The src attribute, surprisingly, is not constrained by the Same Origin Policy. This means that a script element can be created which can go to any server, fetch a script, and execute it. If the script causes the delivery of JSON-encoded data, then this is a very useful thing. Unfortunately, there is no way to constrain the script or to inspect it before it executes. It runs with the same authority as scripts from the page. So the script can access and use its cookies. It can access the originating server using the user's authorization. It can inspect the DOM and the JavaScript global object, and send any information it finds anywhere in the world. The Script Tag Hack is not secure and should be avoided.

http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html

Not really a reference: If this wouldn't work, nobody could include jQuery from Google's CDN and then use it's `$.ajax` method.

Comment: The reason JSONP works is because you can **GET** scripts from anywhere. But what I need to do is **POST** to a server having different domain than the origin of the script. Please clarify your answer a bit more

Comment: Now you're mixing two things. Your script is fetched using *GET* from the CDN. After that, it lives in the domain of app.com

Comment: I don't know what I am not getting here, but a script loaded from domain A can NOT send data to domain B right? If I am right, how can a script loaded from CDN talk to a completely different domain of the app server?

Comment: Replace "loaded from" with "execute in" and your statement is correct. The script tag lives in YOUR document (ajax is part of DOM) and the loaded script is part of YOUR domain, not the CDN's.

Comment: OK, so that means same-origin policy applies ONLY to the execution of the code, and not it's loading? Code loaded from domain X into a domain Y can talk to any domain in the world, but it can not access the code loaded from domain Z into Y. That's the same origin policy -- am I right?

Comment: Code loaded from domain X into a domain Y can only make AJAX requests to Y.

Comment: Loading a script using the script tag's `src` attribute has nothing to do with loading data using `XmlHttpRequest`.

Comment: @Elias are you saying that code loaded from X into Y can not talk to X itself?

Comment: Because the script runs in Y (no matter where it came from...) and thus can talk to Y.

Comment: OK so there's two things: the domain that script comes **FROM** and the domain it comes **INTO**. And, a script can talk to both the domains: from and into -- right?

Comment: Let me put this straight: **origin** (as in same origin policy) refers to the **document**. A script lives inside exactly **one** document (no matter how it got there) and the document comes from **one** domain.

Comment: So, once the script lives in the domain of the document, it can talk to that domain regardless of the domain the script itself comes from?

Comment: yes, I think you got it right now. You ll understand this better if you actually try it